# r - Check if any value in a data.frame column is null

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to see if the data.frame column has any null values to move to the next loop. I am currently using the code below:

```
if (is.na(df[,relevant_column]) == TRUE ){next}
```

which spits out the warning:

> In if (is.na(df_cell_client[, numerator]) == TRUE) { ... :   the
>   condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

How do I check if any of the values are null and not just the first row?

Comment: Use `if (any(is.na(df[,relevant_column]))) {next}`. Without `any`, `is.na(...)` is returning a *vector* of logicals, but `if` needs a single comparison; `any` reduces that to a single logical. The `==TRUE` is unnecessary.

Comment: @r2evans, thanks it worked! If you post the answer I'll select it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(I assume by "null" you really mean `NA`, since a data.frame cannot contain `NULL` in that sense.)

Your problem is that `if` expects a single logical, but `is.na(df[,relevant_column])` is returning a *vector* of logicals. `any` reduces a vector of logicals into a single global "or" of the vector:
Try:

```
if (any(is.na(df[,relevant_column]))) {next}
```

BTW: `== TRUE` is unnecessary. Keep it if you feel you want the clarity in your code, but I think you'll find most R code does not use that. (I've also seen `something == FALSE`, equally "odd/wrong", where `! something` should work ... but I digress.)

Comment: (You might find it preferable to use `anyNA(...)` instead of `any(is.na(...))`. They are functionally equivalent, but `anyNA` can be significantly faster, and it is perhaps more *readable*.)